# Installed web app shows different version than in browser

Tags: caching, web-applications, service-worker, browser-cache

When I load matchflix.ch on my phone, the installed app shows a different version than when I open the site in the phone browser. How can this be?

#### Details

I know that a service worker is in place for offline mode / caching. However, the web app should behave the same in the browser and in the installed web app, since in the service worker I only listen to the fetch event and do nothing on the install event.

#### Reproduction

You can check the difference by showing infos of a movie and then click on the yellow play icon. In the new version, it should show something below, while in the old version, a new website opens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few hours, somehow, the version in the app is now the same as in the browser (as it should be). Still don't understand it really, but so far, the problem seems to be solved...